# Univariate data in a loop R

Tags: r

How can I add each observation, say I have:

```
sim     <- rnorm(10)
 [1]  0.036755133  0.141612338 -0.527639307
 [4]  0.215321316  0.003577324  0.730846811
 [7] -0.346411468 -0.274199832 -0.893520992
[10] -0.991823477
```

now I want to add 10 more observations, where each observation comes one at a time. So assume at t==1 we get 0.54, so now I want

```
     [1]  0.036755133  0.141612338 -0.527639307
     [4]  0.215321316  0.003577324  0.730846811
     [7] -0.346411468 -0.274199832 -0.893520992
    [10] -0.991823477  0.54
```

and so on...stop at the 10 step. Anyone has any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: If you know the data generating process you may be better off pre-allocating a vector `sim <- numeric(20)`. Then filling it in. `sim[1:10] <- rnorm(10)`. In the for loop: `for(i in seq.int(10)) { sim[i + 10L] <- rnorm(1)}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sim <- rnorm(10) # simulated starting data set
```

Method 1:

```
for(1 in 1:10){
   sim <- c(sim, rnorm(1)) # assigns existing data + new obs. to sim
}
```

Method 2:

```
n   <- 10        # loop counter
for(i in 1:10){
  nn     <- n+i  # index
  sim[nn] <- rnorm(1) # add new data
} # You don't strictly have to have these in the for loop but it's a best practice
```

Comment: If I want 0.54 to be the next number?

Comment: @Vic This just uses random data. If you want `.54` to be the next number then just replace `rnorm(1)`  with `my_nums[i]` and assign the values you want to `my_nums` like `my_nums <- c(.54,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.. and so on )`

Answer (score 1):

```
sim <- rnorm(10)
for(i in 1:10)
 sim <- c(sim,rnorm(1))
```